# Using async command MVVM WPF get stuck and UI is frozen

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following view model used in `MainWindow.xaml`, the view model is called `MainViewModel`:

```
public abstract class AbstractPropNotifier : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
      PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public sealed class MainViewModel : AbstractPropNotifier
{
    private bool _editEnabled;
    private bool _deleteEnabled;
    private ICommand _editCommand;
    private ICommand _deleteCommand;
    private IRssViewModel _selectedIrssi;
    private IAsyncCommand _addCommand;

    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

    public MainViewModel(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
      _dispatcher = dispatcher;

      IrssItems = new ObservableCollection<IRssViewModel>();
      Log = new ObservableCollection<string>();
      EditEnabled = false;
      DeleteEnabled = false;

      EditCommand = new RelayCommand(c => EditItem(), p => EditEnabled);
      DeleteCommand = new RelayCommand(DeleteItems, p => DeleteEnabled);
      AddCommand = new AsyncCommand(AddItem, () => true);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IRssViewModel> IrssItems { get; set; }

    public IRssViewModel SelectedIrssi
    {
      get
      {
        return _selectedIrssi;
      }
      set
      {
        _selectedIrssi = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedIrssi));
        EditEnabled = DeleteEnabled = true;
      }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Log { get; set; }

    public bool EditEnabled
    {
      get
      {
        return _editEnabled;
      }
      set
      {
        _editEnabled = value || SelectedIrssi != null;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EditEnabled));
      }
    }

    public bool DeleteEnabled
    {
      get
      {
        return _deleteEnabled;
      }
      set
      {
        _deleteEnabled = value || SelectedIrssi != null;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DeleteEnabled));
      }
    }

    public ICommand EditCommand
    {
      get
      {
        return _editCommand;
      }
      set
      {
        _editCommand = value;
      }
    }

    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
      get
      {
        return _deleteCommand;
      }
      set
      {
        _deleteCommand = value;
      }
    }

    public IAsyncCommand AddCommand
    {
      get
      {
        return _addCommand;
      }
      set
      {
        _addCommand = value;
      }
    }

    private void EditItem()
    {

    }

    private void DeleteItems(object selectedItems)
    {
      var list = selectedItems as IList;
      var newList = new List<IRssViewModel>(list.Cast<IRssViewModel>());

      if (MessageBox.Show($"Are you sure that want to delete {newList.Count} item{(newList.Count > 1 ? "s" : "")} ?", "Deletion", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
      {

        foreach (var item in newList)
        {
          IrssItems.Remove(item as IRssViewModel);
        }

        EditEnabled = DeleteEnabled = false;
      }
    }

    private async Task AddItem()
    {
      var win = new ManageIrssi("Add item");
      var result = win.ShowDialog();

      if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
      {
        foreach (var data in win.Model.Items)
        {
          //check stuff

          IrssItems.Add(data);
          await CreateConnection(data);
        }
      }
    }

    private async Task CreateConnection(IRssViewModel data)
    {
      await Task.Run(() =>
      {
        IrcManager manager = new IrcManager(new CustomLogger(), data);
        manager.Build(s => _dispatcher.Invoke(() => Log.Add(s)));

        data.IsConnected = true;
      });
    }
}
```

and `AsynCommand` is got from https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/

```
public class AsyncCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private bool _isExecuting;
    private readonly Func<Task> _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    private readonly IErrorHandler _errorHandler;

    public AsyncCommand(
        Func<Task> execute,
        Func<bool> canExecute = null,
        IErrorHandler errorHandler = null)
    {
      _execute = execute;
      _canExecute = canExecute;
      _errorHandler = errorHandler;
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
      return !_isExecuting && (_canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true);
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
      if (CanExecute())
      {
        try
        {
          _isExecuting = true;
          await _execute();
        }
        finally
        {
          _isExecuting = false;
        }
      }

      RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
      CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #region Explicit implementations
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
      return CanExecute();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
      ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

The problem I met is that After press a button `Add`, the last line `data.IsConnected = true;` is executed and then nothing happens means UI is frozen and no item is added in UI datagrid.

I removed also part `_dispatcher.Invoke(() => Log.Add(s)`, same issue, UI frozen.

Why ? Where is my mistake ? Seems the problem is in `await CreateConnection(data)`

Comment: Just a note, there doesn't seem to be a need to make the command properties settable. You also don't need a backing field. A declaration like `public IAsyncCommand AddCommand { get; }` seems sufficient. The assignment in the constructor will still work.

Comment: Yeah, I will refactor later. Now, I'm focused on UI issue

Comment: Why did you pass a `Dispatcher`, where it's initialized? You can also try to wrap the logic in `CreateConnection` method into `_dispatcher.InvokeAsync`

Comment: I am hoping that `var win = new ManageIrssi("Add item");` is not a window! Otherwise this is not MvvM! Going back to your issue, when you debug, can you see that you are in a different thread? Also put the dispatcher back in and a breakpoint in there and confirm that you are in the UI thread.

Comment: Does it also deadlock if you use `await CreateConnection(data).ConfigureAwait(false);` ?

Comment: What does Manager.Build does? seems it never returns and your code hence stalls

Comment: Try using a simple ICommand (not this AsyncCommand), with the delegate action being an async void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample code is neither compilable or [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I can spot a flaw in the `Execute` method of your command:

```
void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
{
  ExecuteAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

Calling `Result` on a `Task` may deadlock and is a big no-no, especially in GUI applications. Try to fire away the `Task` and then return from the method:

```
async void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
{
    await ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the issue was from `Execute` one, nice catch !

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `AddItem` is on UI thread and since it is Awaits on UI Thread, your UI stalls.
Take AddItem on new thread and release UI thread, dispatch it to main thread once it is complete and update the UI